# Не создаётся файл

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать файл во внутренней памяти (не на флешке).

```
File file = new  File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "123.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try
{
    outputStream = openFileOutput("123.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write("123.txt".getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Файл не создаётся, смотрю в папке data/data/ а дальше пусто, даже нет папки с названием приложения. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Права выствелны? Чем смотрите, в  data/data так легко не залезть. И папка с пакетом приложения есть всегда.

Comment: я использую genimotion, он позволяет залезть в корень(root)

Comment: пермишн в манифесте указан? WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
public static File createFile(String directory, String name){

    File result;
    do {
        result = new File(directory, name);
    } while (!result.createNewFile());
    return result;
}
```

Свой код измените на

```
File file = createFile(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "123.txt");
```